# Scala - how to sort by Keys and print Properties?

Tags: scala, sorting

I have a working scala code:

```
val props = new java.util.Properties
...
props.forEach((key, value) => {
   println("|" + key + "|: " + value)
})
```

This will print properties Key -> Value.

How to do the same but sort by Keys and print?

Thanks.

Comment: Why adding the `Java` tag on a scala question?

Comment: DamCx, at least it uses the native Java class, so it is generally undecidable, which language lies closer to the proper answer without looking at refdocs. :)